# If form2 has been closed winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that gets a group of values from a second form and passes this to another list in the main form, However if form2 is closed no values will be passed. Due to this I want to detect if form two has been closed.

Currently my code looks if the list is empty:

```
if (BoxValues == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(" stopped!");
    fileProcessBar.Value = 0;
    return;
}
```

But this is not really what I am looking for I have also tried the following:

```
if (CF.Isdisposed)
{
    MessageBox.Show(" stopped!");
    fileProcessBar.Value = 0;
    return;
}
```

but this just passes the If statement. My second form is called CF any ideas on a better way to handle this?

**Edit**

This would just be on a closing event that this should trigger, if the form holds values it should move onto the `else` statement.

Comment: The question is a little unclear, but I suspect you need to make "form2" actually a dialog...

Comment: Can you give us a little more context, please? We don't see an else statement, nor can we determine why it should "move onto" it ...

Comment: Do you really care for the form or is it just the values you are interested in? If the latter is the case, you should use some MVC ...

Comment: Are you actually trying to figure out whether the user clicked `X` or `OK`?

Comment: @SLaks I also suspect that he actually wants to use some sort of custom dialog. He just doesn't know yet.

Comment: @Slaks, yeah preferably this is when a user presses `x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the [Application.OpenForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection and search if it contains a form with the name of your probably closed form. If you find something there then an instance of that form is not yet closed (it could also be hidden)

```
if(Application.OpenForms["CF"] == null)
{   
    MessageBox.Show(" stopped!");
    fileProcessBar.Value = 0;
    return;
}
```

Another possible approach is wire the second form closed event to an event handler running in your main form. The code in this event handler knows immediately when the form is closed and could set a global class level variable to be used in your if statement. However, if you don't have to react immediately at the form closure this second approach is more cumbersome than looking at the OpenForms collection just when you need it

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `Visible` property, which will be false if the form is hidden, even before it's disposed.

Comment: Should he not be looking for the `OnClosed`/`OnClosing` events instead?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: His question is unclear, but it sounds like he's looking for a property, not an event.

Comment: @Slaks, this would trigger no matter what thought right? I mean if the form holds values it would need to move onto the `else` statement.

Comment: @Tom: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: just to mention the point that OnClosed and OnClosing are methods not events, Closed and Closing are the actual events, and also Closed event is obsolete as of. Net 2.0 in favor of FormClosed

Comment: @EsnEzz I've not used WinForms for the past 3 years or so :) close enough

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OpenForms collection to determine if the form is loaded/opened.  I believe that is available in the Application class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx